# read() return positive but there is nothing in recvline

Tags: c, sockets

I'm using socket in C, and I want to ask, is that normal read return positive value but read nothing?

```
#define MAXLINE 1234
....
upload(){
....
    long long unsigned int byteNum = 0, count = 0;
    ssize_t nbyte;
    char sendline[MAXLINE], recvline[MAXLINE];
....
    while((count += byteNum) < filesize) {
        bzero(sendline, MAXLINE);
        if((byteNum = fread(&sendline, sizeof(char), MAXLINE, fp)) != MAXLINE ){
            printf("End of file or Error\n");
        }
        if((nbyte = write(sockfd, sendline, byteNum)) < 0){
            printf("upload write error at count = %llu\n", count);
            exit(1);
        }read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE);
    }
....

}

download(){
....
    long long unsigned int filesize, count;
    ssize_t nbyte;
    char sendline[MAXLINE], recvline[MAXLINE];
....
        while((count += n) < filesize){
                bzero(recvline, MAXLINE);
                if((nbyte = read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE)) < 0){
                    printf("download read fail at %llu\n", count);
                    exit(1);
                }if(nbyte == 0){
                    printf("nbyte = 0!!\n");
                    return;
                }if(strlen(recvline) == 0){
                    printf("nbyte = %zd recvline = 0\n", nbyte);
                    return;
                }
                n = strlen(recvline);
                if(fwrite(&recvline, sizeof(char), nbyte, fp) != nbyte)
                    printf("end of file or error\n");
                write(sockfd, "ok", 2);                 
            }
....
}
```

result

```
nbyte = 1234 recvline = 0
```

it happens only when the file size is large(in test case, it's about 5GB), but in about 50MB it's work well.

What might be wrong?

---

I have changed the type of nbyte(from unsigned long long into ssize_t)

but the result remains the same

Comment: Don't post external links and/or images of text! How does that behaviour contradict the documentation of the functions?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Are you sure `nbyte` is a signed type?

Comment: i'm sorry this is mt first post, i will edit it right away

Comment: Are your variables able to hold the filesize?

Comment: `nbyte 65535` in the image looks very much like hte value of `-1` assigned to an unsigned 16-bit int.

Comment: `printf("nbyte = %llu recvline = 0\n", nbyte);` ... how can that print a negative value?

Comment: Note that `read()` doesn't null-terminate the buffer. Calling `strlen()` on a buffer you have just `read()` into is probably undefined behavior.

Comment: it's 65535 because I set it be, type of nbyte is unsigned long long, I know for sure because I just set the MAXLINE be 1234, it nbyte is 1234

Comment: "*`printf("nbyte = %llu recvline = 0\n", nbyte);`*" `read()` returns `ssize_t` not `unsigned long long`.

Comment: An `unsigned` would never be `< 0`, so this "*`((nbyte = read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE)) < 0)`*" will never be true. You invented the unbreakable way to call `read()`! ;-)

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: Look, read() is well-documented.  Fix your types and any calls, (like strlen), that require null-terminated char arrays that are called on buffers that are, well, not guaranteed to be null-terminated char arrays.

Comment: 'long long unsigned nbyte' and 'if((nbyte = read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE)) < 0)' do you get it yet?

Comment: I'm now change the type of nbyte, and then test if it fix the problem

Comment: Also, why is amost every read/recv call always stuffed into a compound expression to make it difficult to read?  Will someone please burninate the website with that code that devs. keep copying from!

Comment: @MartinJames: "*difficult to read?*" that's why I always turn it around like: `if (0 > (nbyte = read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE))) {` easily to parse from left to right ...! Yes, beat me ... ;-)

Comment: So now, how is `recvline` defined?

Comment: @alk then you get moaned at for yoda conditionals - you cannot win:)

Comment: char recvline[MAXLINE];

Comment: I Yoda gammar adore ... ;-)  @MartinJames

Comment: Ok then change it to  be `char recvline[MAXLINE + 1];`  and as 1st statement inside the while-loop set it to all `0`s by doing: `memset(recvline, 0, MAXLINE + 1]);`. To `recv()` you still would pass `MAXLINE`!

Comment: If `read` returns a positive number, then it wrote that many bytes to the buffer; that's guaranteed by the API contract.  If `strlen` returns zero, then the first byte of its argument buffer is `'\0'`; that is also an API guarantee.  Put those two things together: the first byte `read` wrote to the buffer must have been `'\0'`. Is it possible that your "large file" contains bytes with that value, whereas your "small file" doesn't?

Comment: ok, I will change it right away

Comment: And you do transfer text files only, don't you?

Comment: @zwol I don't know, my large file is a 5GB wmv, and small file is a 50MB txt

Comment: It's kinda like this, @VitoChou, 99.9% of all str* calls in network code are bad.

Comment: @alk the large file is a wmv file

Comment: Yup - that's gonna have nulls in it, for sure..

Comment: .wmvs are binary, you cannot handle such data using the members of the `str*()` family of functions. Those are to handle (textual) "strings".

Comment: I am checking other kind of file now

Comment: You want to read on how "string"s are handle in C. -oo-

Comment: If all you want to do is copy files around, then the `strlen` calls in your code are completely unnecessary.  Just call `fwrite(recvline, 1, nbyte, fp)`.

Comment: (Footnote: `sizeof(char)` is *defined* to be 1 by the C standard. Therefore, writing `sizeof(char)` is redundant and makes your code harder to read.)

Comment: originally, there is no strlen in it, but the large file always gone wrong
I have tried many other ways to figure where might be wrong, but I really don't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using socket in C, and I want to ask, is that normal read return
>   positive value but read nothing?

No, that's not normal -- on success, read() always returns the number of bytes that it placed into your buffer.

> What might be wrong?

It looks like you are trying to handle binary data as if it was ASCII text data.  That won't work, because binary data will likely have NUL/zero bytes in it, and if you try to treat it as text data (e.g. by calling strlen()/strcmp()/strcpy()/etc on it) those functions will be fooled by the presence of those NUL bytes, since those functions expect a NUL byte to indicate the end of a string.

In particular, what you're seeing is that sometimes the first byte written into your recvline is a 0, and that is why strlen(recvline) returns 0 even though read() wrote one or more valid bytes into recvline.